# Blob filtering using opencv in python

Tags: python, opencv

Needed to detect red color from an image and get the coordinates based on screen size.

- Using mask fetched the part of image having red color
- Converted it to BW
- Applied Gaussian filter to it.

The final image has small bodies which I need to remove and fetch the coordinates of the rest. I tried SimpleBlobDetector, but did not help. This is my code -

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img=cv2.imread("D:\Ankur\Free\line.png")
img_hsv=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)


lower_red = np.array([0,50,50])
upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])
mask0 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_red, upper_red)


lower_red = np.array([170,50,50])
upper_red = np.array([180,255,255])
mask1 = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower_red, upper_red)


mask = mask0+mask1


output_img = img.copy()
output_img[np.where(mask==0)] = 0


gray = cv2.cvtColor(output_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Adaptive Gaussian Thresholding
gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray,5)
th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
cv2.imshow("images", th3)
#cv2.ims
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the image I am using and the final image -

Original image:

[image]

after gaussian filter

[image]

Comment: Why not try finding contours? Find contours and reject smaller ones based on the area or perimeter and retain the bigger ones. Then draw a rectangle around the remaining big contours are obtain the coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on OpenCV 3.0, I would suggest you to look at `connectedComponentsWithStats`function.

Else, the below snippet cleans the image with opening and closing, then finds the contours. Then it draws the contours and contour centers.

```
# Create a kernel
kernel = np.ones((7,7),np.uint8)
# Use opening to fill the blobs
opened = cv2.morphologyEx(th3, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
# Use closing to disconnect the bridges
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(opened, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Create a color image to show the result
new_img = cv2.cvtColor(closed, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
# Invert the image 
closed=255-closed
# Find contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contours:
    # Skip if the contour area is small
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area < 500:
        continue
    # Draw the contour
    cv2.drawContours(new_img, [cnt], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
    # Find the center
    M = cv2.moments(cnt)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    # Draw the center
    cv2.circle(new_img, (cX, cY), 7, (0, 0, 255), -1)

cv2.imwrite("result.png",new_img)
```

I got the following result, hope it was what you were describing, and hope it works for you too.

[image]

Comment: I am getting following error - ValueError: too many values to unpack for getting the contours

Comment: findContours implementation varies between OpenCV versions. Since I don't know your version, it was mismatched. Try `_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(...)` instead.

Comment: thnx it worked... I had opencv 3.0... but as you suggested connectedComponentsWithStats marked areas but not on the line. But this helped. Thanks a lot.