# OpenCV - Object detection in Video

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I have a video and am trying to detect an object in the video.

I am using Background subtraction to get the foreground and find the object using that. The problem is with background subtraction; I do detect the image but along with it detect some of the background too around the object.

I am wondering how i could get rid of the area around the object. Although for our eye its pretty easy to distinguish what can we accurately do to detect the object?

[My Object is the black thing at the very right][1]

Comment: Background subtraction is a very crude way to identify blobs, it's generally used with some kind of thresholding to eliminate noise and other artefacts. Is there any kind of motion in your source video? What is the ultimate aim of your exercise?

Comment: Also please clarify if your task is **detection** (*if something* is there) or **identification** (*what something* is). They are very different problems - and one is considerably harder than the other.

Comment: @Dai Hey Dai, Thanks for quick response. I am using Background Subtraction since there is motion (the object moves around while the background is relatively stable). The problem im trying to solve is detection not identification (sorry for not explaining it properly). I want to know where the object is in various frames, and write it to a file. I can kind of detect the object around the frame but the problem is some frames the background detection detects some of the green background too around the object. I want to make it a bit more accurate (the size of the object)

Comment: I considered color detection but its not really accurate especially since sometimes the background isn't plain green.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blob filtering using opencv in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441397/blob-filtering-using-opencv-in-python)

Comment: @JKlain Instead of only detecting the object, why not place a rectangle around it? It is much more appropriate for videos